# Обновление (обнуление) данных в элементах формы

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте! У меня возникла такая проблема.

Необходимо в обработчике по нажатию кнопки сбрасывать все данные элементов форм (т.е. очистить TextBox, сбросить флажки и радио кнопки).

Подскажите, каким образом это можно сделать?

Если использовать

```
Application.Restart();
```

то заметно, что приложение просто перезапускается, да и переменные обнуляются.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Получаете список контролов формы, по каждому из них проходитесь, проверяя тип контрола, и в зависимости от типа или удаляете текст, или меняете свойство Checked на false, и так далее. Помните, что контролы могут быть контейнерами, содержащими другие контролы, поэтому следует предусмотреть вариант рекурсивного обхода коллекции контролов формы

Comment: спасибо большое, разобрался.